# What's the best way to save a checkboxlist so the user can open the list after re-log

Tags: php, mysql, storage, checkboxlist

I'm able to get all the checked values but I have to reconstruct the whole Checklist again.

Properties of the checkboxlist:

- New Chechboxes are added dynamcially after checking one checkbox
- You can add manually add new checkboxes through button click

What's the best way to storage the checklist into database, so I can easily open it again and again, without loosing data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the existing values as an encoded json string and store it in the database.

Suppose, you're having multiple checkboxes with different values:

```
$data[chkbox1][0] = 1;  // Example data
$data[chkbox1][1] = 0;
$data[chkbox2][0] = 3;
$data[chkbox2][1] = 2;

// Store this variable in database & Convert into base64, to keep it simple    
$jsonstring = base64_encode(json_encode($data));
```

Once you've stored the string in the database, after you retrieve it back, you can do something like this:

```
$data = json_decode(base64_decode($sqldata));
```

This way you'll get your data back!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tzar. Is it possible to rebuild the checkboxlist again? I actually got all the checkbox data by myself but I have to make it more userfriendly by rebuilding the checkboxlist and atuomatically checking the last saved checkboxes.

Comment: Maybe if you can provide some code snippet so that we can get some idea on what you actually want